# Why is $wp->request empty in Wordpress 6.0?

Tags: php, urls

Trying to obtain the page url with the following code prior to Wordpress 6.0 works, but after update to Wordpress 6.0, `$wp->request` is coming through as an empty string on all pages.  I have Post name set in permalinks under Common Settings if that matters.

The code below no longer works for getting the current url in the browser:

```
add_query_arg($wp->query_vars, $wp->request);
```

If there a new way to obtain the current url in the browser with Wordpress 6.0?  I would need to obtain it as early as possible.  The code above worked as is directly within the functions.php file without any hooks.  Is there something similar to this in Wordpress 6.0?

**EDIT:  Tested with a Fresh install of Wordpress 6.0**

This is also happening after installing a Fresh copy of Wordpress 6.0 in the twentytwentytwo theme functions.php file (placed the following at the top of the file):

```
global $wp;

$current_url = add_query_arg($wp->query_vars, $wp->request);

error_log(var_export($current_url, true));
error_log(var_export($wp->request, true));
```

Look at `wp-content/debug.log` and see that both are empty strings no matter what url you go to on the site, or what your permalink settings are set to.  Obviously, you will need to enable the debug log in wp-config.php first.

What is the correct way in Wordpress to obtain the current page url?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive that the code worked directly in the functions.php file at the very top and outputted the correct url, for example, in header.php and in footer.php on pages it could be used easily, and was in the functions.php file without any hooks.  It was also possible to get the page url from an ajax call easily as well.

Comment: And there might be a better way to do what you're trying to do, so why do you need to get the current URL and why must it be directly in the functions file?

Comment: Because I need to obtain it from ajax calls, where many wordpress actions don't get called.

Comment: But I also need to check the url for when a form gets submitted because I'm using the url as a slug to get data from wp_options table in some instances where specific api keys are attached to urls on the site.

Comment: The `wp` hook is no good here.  And I wouldn't want to insert this into a variable in javascript using `wp_localize_script`, as it wouldn't be secure.  It should be processed in PHP and handled that way instead.

Comment: Lol sorry, my bad (and I deleted my 1st comment), I actually described the behavior when the code is put directly in the root of a main plugin file... 

Comment: Admin AJAX calls or REST API AJAX calls? Why do you need the current URL in that particular context? It seems like a strange thing to need when you're at a known URL already. Is there a specific reason you're using this specific solution to get the URL rather than a general PHP solution?

Comment: I found the cause, and it was pre-announced on the Make WP Blogs in April

Comment: Can you share a link to that announcement maybe?

Comment: @SolomonClosson it's on the official WP.org make blog, specifically the core blog. Every single WP release has a fieldguide post that lists all the announcements and goes out just after release, this is the one for WP 6.0: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/05/03/wordpress-6-0-field-guide/

Comment: @SolomonClosson, "The `wp` hook is no good here" - if you're actually running the code in question on the page that you're making the AJAX request from, then it's unlikely that, with a stock WordPress setup, `wp` would not work. I'm just curious, btw.

Comment: @SolomonClosson where are your AJAX requests being handled? Also `add_query_arg($wp->query_vars, $wp->request)` isn't an official solution to getting the URL, it's just a one liner someone discovered once, as I mentioned in my answer there is a general way to do this in PHP that you haven't used.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I can use `home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` or just `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and that will work, but this also grabs everything requested, not just the url.  This seems to get the ajax url also `admin-ajax.php` which I really don't care for.

Comment: I'm just trying to find a correct Wordpress way of doing this now in Wordpress 6.0 unless there is no way to do this anymore?  I just don't understand why they would remove this functionality as it worked perfect for all urls, archives, tags, etc. etc.

Comment: Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is returning all image urls on the page as well as even the favicon.ico file.  It's not a good way of doing this.

Comment: @SolomonClosson the code you're using was never the official way to do it, your report that REQUEST_URI also contains all the image URLs though is perplexing, this doesn't make sense unless you're bundling them. You can parse the URL and get just the part you want using PHP, you don't need a WordPress specific solution for this, and my understanding of what you're trying to do is that you will always get `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` as the value, clearly there is more to this than you've explained. Where and when is your code running?

Comment: e.g. what you've said implies the `$wp->request` code is running in a classic `admin-ajax.php` handler, but AJAX handlers don't have favicons and images, are you actually running this on the frontend then sending it to an AJAX handler? Please provide more context for what you're doing and more code for what surrounds this, as well as how and where you are processing it. There's a very strong possibility that you've built something in a way that has a much simpler alternative, or that you're hiding key information that you don't think is relevant to keep it super abstract/generic

Comment: Also, `REQUEST_URI` will include all GET parameters, if you want it to only include query vars you can still do that, and there are other PHP solutions than `REQUEST_URI`, e.g. `parse_url`, what you've been using was always non-canonical and non-standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct way in Wordpress to obtain the current page url?

You don't, WP has never provided a way to do this, the closest is `get_permalink` which provides the canonical URL of the current post.

What you've been using is unofficial, and never gave you the actual URL as it only appended the whitelisted query variables that `WP_Query` accepts.

Instead, WordPress is just a CMS built in PHP, and PHP has a solution. You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the full URL, instead, then parse out only the parts you want.

E.g.

```php
$url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$path = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH );
add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, $path );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

---

Additionally, you might have `do_parse_request` filters that return `false` or an equivalent value, or most likely they return nothing at all ( aka `null` ), causing WP to bypass this. The cause of this is a change in WordPress 6.0 that was announced in April:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/04/27/changes-to-do_parse_request-filter-in-wordpress-6-0/

However this is unlikely to be the cause of your issue.

Comment: There is no filter `do_parse_request` in the theme at all, so are you saying I would need to add it in order to obtain a non-empty string from `$wp->request`?

Comment: There is also no `do_parse_request` filters added to any of the plugins installed.  So not sure why it is returning empty string.  I'm going to test now with a completely new install of Wordpress to be sure.  Thanks for finding that info.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is related to the problem honestly, but we'll find out on a completely fresh install of Wordpress 6.0 with No plugins.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is also returning an empty value for $wp->request on the twentytwentytwo theme right after a fresh install of Wordpress 6.0 placing the following code at the top of functions.php, the error log (debug.log) shows empty string on all pages:  `global $wp;

$current_url = add_query_arg($wp->query_vars, $wp->request);

error_log(var_export($current_url, true));`

Comment: Please see updated question.  Not sure how to fix this, as this is what is happening right out of the box in Wordpress now.  This was not the case in the previous versions.

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate that there are PHP based solutions.

Comment: also funfact: `add_query_arg($wp->query_vars,'');` works in WP 5.8, `$wp->request` doesn't need to contain anything, `add_query_arg` will actually attempt to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if no URL is provided which may have been what was letting your original code work all along https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/. Consider trying `add_query_arg($wp->query_vars )`

Comment: Thanks, `add_query_arg($wp->query_vars )` works a charm.  I didn't even think to remove the 2nd parameter as I thought it was needed.

Comment: Thanks for your time and with investigating all of this.  Very Much Appreciated.  It was odd for me to see it not working the same.

Comment: Actually @SolomonClosson, `add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars )` in your case, is equivalent to `add_query_arg( array() )` and `add_query_arg( '' )`.. *if* I was correct that you're running the code on the front-end or the page where the AJAX request is being made from. Because if so, then the issue in question happened because `$wp->query_vars` was an empty **array** because WordPress hadn't yet parsed the request. In previous WordPress versions, that property defaults to a `NULL` which basically why `add_query_arg()` gave you a correct URL - or used the `REQUEST_URI` value.

Comment: And what I'm trying to say is, your code **runs too early** and you should instead wait until WordPress has finished parsing the request, e.g. by hooking on `parse_request`. That way, `$wp->query_vars` and `$wp->request` would have the proper values by the time your code runs.

Comment: I agree with Sally, the code running too early and running on the page that makes the AJAX request, not the AJAX handler, would explain a lot of the weirdness you've described. There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're doing, and there's a very high chance you're doing something weird that directly affects this we're unaware of, but without knowing or seeing it we can only speculate

Comment: Thanks guys, I just need to make sure that the url in the browser loads all of the time via PHP (Server-side) as the first thing, as early as possible.  the `wp` hook is not early enough, maybe the `parse_request` hook could work?  Haven't tried that hook, but seems promising.  Would need to be loaded before the AJAX actions are called ofcourse.

Comment: when you visit a page the AJAX actions do not load, AJAX actions and handling AJAX events are a completely different request. Remember, each request to WordPress loads WordPress from a blank slate, the PHP code that grabs the URL has no interactions with the PHP code that handles your AJAX, the only thing connecting the two is the javascript that runs the AJAX. For this reason, a lot of your last comment doesn't make sense, there is no shared persisted state or variables between the two. This would be much easier if you told us what you're building

Comment: Remember, AJAX requests are handled by `admin-ajax.php` in a totally separate request, that has nothing to do with generating the page. WP is not like Java or Node servers, it doesn't constantly run in the background listening

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining that.  But the functions.php file gets loaded via ajax, even if it doesn't load any of the actions in there besides the ajax actions, it does load the functions.php file.

Comment: For example, I can set a global variable in functions.php and than use that global variable inside of the ajax actions.

Comment: `functions.php` is always loaded, even when there is no web request, e.g. cron jobs, WP CLI, but as I keep saying, you should tell us what it is that you're building, by hiding it you make it extremely difficult and confusing